# Vapor app failing to deploy on Heroku: We don't have Build instructions for ’5.1.3’

Tags: ios, swift, git, heroku, vapor

I am trying to deploy a Vapor 4 app on Heroku. It's failing with the following error:

```
   remote: Building source:
   remote: 
   remote: -----> Swift app detected
   remote: -----> Using Swift ’5.1.3’ (from .swift-version file)
   remote: -----> Installing clang 7.0.1
   remote: -----> Installing Swiftenv
   remote: -----> Installing Swift ’5.1.3’
   remote: We don't have Build instructions for ’5.1.3’.
   remote:!     Push rejected, failed to compile the Swift app.
   remote: 
   remote:!     Push failed
   remote: Verifying deploy...
   remote: 
   remote:! Push rejected to 
   remote:
```

This is my package description:

```swift
// swift-tools-version:5.1
import PackageDescription
       
let package = Package(
       name: "ashi-apns",
       platforms: [
          .macOS(.v10_15),
       ],
       dependencies: [
         //  A server-side Swift web framework.
          .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/fluent.git", from: "4.0.0-rc"),
          .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/fluent-postgresql.git", from: "2.0.0-rc"),
          .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git", from: "4.3.0"),
          .package(url: "https://github.com/kylebrowning/APNSwift.git", from: "2.0.0-rc1"),
          .package(url: "https://github.com/MihaelIsaev/FCM.git", from: "2.7.0"),
          //.package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/jwt.git", from: "4.0.0-rc"),    
          // .product(name: "Leaf", package: "leaf"),
          //.package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/leaf.git", from: "4.0.0-rc"), //.product(name: "JWT", package: "jwt"), 
      ],
      targets: [
         .target(
            name: "App", 
            dependencies: [
              .product(name: "Fluent", package: "fluent"),
              .product(name: "FluentPostgresDriver", package: "fluent-postgres-driver"),
              .product(name: "Vapor", package: "vapor"),
              "APNSwift",
              .product(name: "FCM", package: "FCM"),
            ]),
               
            .target(name: "Run", dependencies: [
               .target(name: "App"),
            ]),
               
            .testTarget(name: "AppTests", dependencies: [
               .target(name: "App"),
            ])
        ]
 )
```

and I'm using this buildpack:

```
heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/vapor-community/heroku-buildpack
```

With the same buildpack I am able to deploy v3 apps.

Why can't Heroku build Swift 5.1.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Using Swift ’5.1.3’ (from .swift-version file)
> ```

Those quotes look funny. I bet your `.swift-version` file literally contains

```
’5.1.3’
```

Whereas it *should* contain

```
5.1.3
```

Get rid of the quotes, commit, and deploy again.